# Hidden html table for data storage

Tags: javascript, json, data-storage

I have built a one page web application that manipulates a set of data:

- 2,000 to 3,000 items
- each item has the same properties: State, City, Street, Zip code

I am currently retrieving the data via AJAX and storing them in an array of objects (each array element is an object with key/value for State, City, Street, Zip code).

I am considering modifying my code, to store my items in a hidden html table instead:

- one row per item
- one column per property (State, City, Street, Zip code)

The main benefit I see: when they work offsite, the users can save my page to work offline, as the hidden table is part of the DOM.

A table is also a convenient format, all browsers understand it (I need to support IE 7), and each cell is easy to access by its coordinates (rows[i].cells[j]).

I am a little bit concerned with performance for DOM traversing, but I am thinking that I could have the table detached from the DOM, and only attach it when users save the page.

Am I missing something? Is there any reason in my case why using a hidden table for data storage wouldn't be a good idea?

Comment: Write it to HTML5 spec and use localized storage

Comment: Sounds cool, but i would definitely use jQuery to make your life easier if you are going to be manipulating the data very often on the client.

Comment: @thenetimp +1 , but does IE7 support that?

Comment: @thenetimp see my question, HTML 5 is not an option as I need to support IE 7.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would cripple functionality in any decent browser? I would suggest you use WebSQL / IndexedDB and fallback to just local javascript variables for browsers like IE 7. So when you reload the page, it still has the stored data in decent browsers.

Comment: @JorisKluivers +1 it seems that I am headed for a fallback option for IE 7 / IE 8.

Comment: Sorry i haven't used localized storage myself so I wasn't aware ie7 didn't support it.

Comment: window.name can hold up to 4MB of string data. You can stringify and shove JSON in there for IE7.

Comment: @Diodeus +1 interesting, thx for the idea. Although using a technique that has a hard limit is always a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON. It is by far the most efficient and fastest way to access data on the client. Travering a DOM using a table would be an order of magnitude slower. You can easily save your JSON data as a text blob in any database or storage system as well.

The [EXT.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/) framework uses JSON extensively and I've found it to be a great tool for the job.

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but wouldn't traversing be much faster if the table is detached from the DOM?

Comment: It would be. I agree, but JSON is native to JavaScript itself, and is therefore faster than any form of external hook.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET you can do put this in the head of the page with a literal.

**JSON on Pageload**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table1 = [      
    // First Row
    {"Column1" : "Col1Data", 
      "Column2" : "Col2Data",
     "Column3" : "Col3Data" },

    // Second Row
    {"Column1"  : "Col1Data",  
     "Column2" : "Col2Data",
     "Column3" : "Col3Data" }
     ]

</script>
```

Then you can access the data with:

```
table1[rowNum].ColumnName;
```

Comment: definitely, that's one more reason why tables look like a good option. My current question and concern is more about the drawbacks of tables.

Comment: JSON would be faster than selecting dom elements, but if you want to have offline capability, if they reloaded the page, the data would be available in the html, but not in json. However, if you stored the data in a json object in say script in the page load, it would be there in offline pageloads too, which may be faster.  You might have to generate that script server-side and pass it in that way for the data to remain in the actual html.

Comment: @Christophe I've changed my answer above to create a JSON object on the page load. If you go this route, just make sure that the actual data is in the html page, or working offline won't work, as the browser needs the data in the page to create the JSON objects.